# py2exe generator not working

Tags: py2exe

I ran this setup.py file

```
from distutils.core import setup

import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundles_files': 1}},

    windows = [{'script': "Driverscript.py"}],

    zipfile = None,

)
```

This creates the executable file and packages but it wont run every time i try to run it it says that it encountered an error and had to close every time. Is there something else i need to do first or something wrong with my setup.py file? all input is greatly appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

What's the output of your error log? That could mean a lot of things. I'm assuming you're compiling a windowing application? Are you running this application on Windows? You might want to run the application from the command line and see if you get any errors.

Comment: i still got errors running it from the command line ive tried about 3 different scripts for setup.py and they all compile but they wont run the application